# Prove This Bool Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Prove $x'z+xyz+xy'z=z$ can you show how you solve this using Boolean Algebra.

My main problem is when I do this $xz (y + y') = 1 $
So $1$ times $x =$ ?

Comment: $$xz(y+y')=xz$$ and $x'z+xz=z(x'+x)=z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ x'z + xyz + xy'z = z $$
$$ x'z + xz (y + y') \ // AssociationRule$$
$$ x'z + xz * 1  \ // \ a + a' = 1; a * 1 = a $$ 
$$ z (x'+x) \ // \ a + a' = 1$$
$$ z * 1 \ // \ a * 1 = a $$ 
$$ z $$

Answer (score 0):

How about simply
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x'z + xyz + xy'z &=& (x'+xy+xy')z \\
&=&(x'+x(y+y'))z \\
&=&(x'+x)z \\
&=& z,
\end{eqnarray}
$$
using the distributive laws and $x+x'=1$.